# how to use spring cache with two properties as key

Tags: java, spring, spring-cache

Refer to [Spring Cache](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-store-configuration-jdk) which can be used to cache the service calls.

Specially the following xml snippet:

```
<!-- the service we want to make cacheable -->
<bean id="bookService" class="x.y.service.DefaultBookService"/>

<!-- cache definitions -->
<cache:advice id="cacheAdvice" cache-manager="cacheManager">
    <cache:caching cache="books">
        <cache:cacheable method="findBook" key="#isbn"/>
        <cache:cache-evict method="loadBooks" all-entries="true"/>
    </cache:caching>
</cache:advice>

<!-- apply the cacheable behavior to all BookService interfaces -->
<aop:config>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="cacheAdvice" pointcut="execution(* x.y.BookService.*(..))"/>
</aop:config>
```

The above mechanism works if the key is a single property. I need to cache based on isbn and author.

Can somebody suggest how can the caching be enabled using two properties?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could easily use `key="#author.toString() + #isbn.toString()")` or implement your own keyGenerator  and configure it or you just omit the key attribute so that all arguments are taken into account.